# Apply drop caps to the first word in a paragraph?

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

Simple question: Within paragraph styles, is there a way to tell inDesign to create drop caps not using a set amount of characters at the beginning of a paragraph, but instead using the **first word** of the paragraph, regardless of how long it is?

**(Except setting the drop caps individually for each paragraph!)**

Answer (score 2):

First create a `Window > Styles > Character Style` that defines how you want the drop caps to look. Name it whatever you want.
[image: Character Style]
Then create a `Window > Styles > Paragraph Style`. In the `Drop Caps and Nested Styles` section, click `New Nested Style`, and then set the style pull down to the Character Style you created earlier, and (should be the default) make sure it says `through` `1` and `Words` for the remaining pull downs.
[image: Drop Caps and Nested Styles]

Comment: Well that is a good way to automatically apply a Character Style to the first word of each paragraph, but with the Character Style, there is no way to create a drop caps effect, or is there?
+ 1 for something I didn't knew before though!

Comment: Ah, true... I wasn't thinking of the true drop-cap effect - just formatting. Sorry, I'm not sure how to drop cap just the first word.

Comment: The "Drop Caps" line above "Nested Styles" is where you want to set your Drop Cap properties. Unfortunately you can only define "number of characters" there, so if your first word is more than that number of characters, it doesn't work.